# How to use popUntil properly to reach the root of the stack?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have pushed to two screen and wish to go back to my main home page. I tried doing that by using popUntil however it is not giving me the req result and just showing a black screen. Do i need to set a new route to my main page , even though i don't want to create a new instance of it ?

My code:

```
class Completed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Completed Screen',
      home: CompleteScreen(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
       // "/my-app": (BuildContext context) => MyApp()
      }
 );
}
}

class CompleteScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

    Container Complete = Container(
        child: Column(
           .....
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){        
                      Navigator.popUntil(
                        context,
                        ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                      ); 
                      // Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));
                    },              
                ),

          ],
        ));

    return Scaffold(
        body:  Complete
    );
  }
}
```

My main page

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: DefaultTabController(length: 2,child: MyHomePage(title: '')),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
       "/TaskScreen": (BuildContext context) => new task(),
      }
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

   final list =  ListView.builder(
     itemBuilder: (context, position) {
       return Ink(
         child: InkWell(
           onTap: (){
             Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/TaskScreen");
           },
           child: Card(
             ...
           ),),); },);

   return Scaffold(
   ...
 }
}
```

I tried using '/TaskScreen' and '/my-app' however even that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
Navigator.popUntil(
      context,
      ModalRoute.withName(
        Navigator.defaultRouteName,
      ),
    ),
```

As `defaultRouteName` works as the first screen opened when the app starts.

**EDIT**

So, as mentioned below, named routes won't work with `Navigator.defaultRouteName`nor `route.isFirst`, the best approach to solve this I've found is declaring all your routes in the main page, as these will become global *(or that's what I understood)*, so your code would end something like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: DefaultTabController(length: 2,child: MyHomePage(title: '')),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        "/": (BuildContext context) => MyApp(), (or MyHomePage())
        "/TaskScreen": (BuildContext context) => new task(),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

With that done, anytime you want to go back to the main page you just have to call

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: it is not working..button click is not leading to anything. I tried to simple pop using Navigator.of(context).pop(); to check if my pop mechanism is working properly but it leads to a black screen and not showing the previous screen

Comment: I just found that if you're using named routes, neither `Navigator.defaultRouteName`nor `route.isFirst`will work.
I'll do some further research.

Comment: Check the edit, maybe it'll work this time.
I'm sorry for the bad english beforehand.

Comment: Hi I figured out my mistake ... I had used another materialApp under the wrong assumption that the routes for that page need to be set up from its home. Now i realized my mistake and removed the other MaterialApps. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The route in the `popUntil` has a property called `isFirst` that returns true if the route is the first route in the navigator. So in your case, you can use something like:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) {
      return route.isFirst;
    });
```